# Can't install TBB using Homebrew on MacOS

Tags: macos, command, homebrew, tbb

I have been trying to install TBB using Homebrew on my MacOS Ventura Hackintosh (AMD) and I have been unable to even install anything using Homebrew. Here's the output of running `brew install tbb` `sam@adsl ~ % brew install tbb Warning: No available formula with the name "tbb". ==> Searching for similarly named formulae... Error: No similarly named formulae found. ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)... Error: No previously deleted formula found. ==> Searching taps on GitHub... Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: What does the `brew doctor` command say on your hackingtoch? Does it output: "Your system is ready to brew"?

Comment: You want to install package that is not existent in brew repository, please find correct name of it and then redo the step. Also I use my AMD Hackintosh almost every day and brew works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your brew installation seems corrupt.

Run these commands to resolve and fix issue:
% brew update
% brew upgrade
% brew doctor

Doctor can report a number of warnings:

- Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
  You may wish to link these or uninstall these.
- Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /opt/homebrew/bin in your PATH.
  You may wish to modify your PATH to put homebrew first.